# Youtube Analytics API OAuth 2.0 authentication issue. The authentication page doesn't load forever

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

This is my script, and I am using the same localhost in my API OAuth as well. What is happening?

The page remains stuck on this verification forever without ever picking the Key:

[image: The page remains stuck on this verification forever without ever picking the Key]

We're attempting to generate a link for authentication to my google account for verification.
The script fetches daily analytics (views, likes, dislikes, average view duration) from the YouTube Analytics API for a specified YouTube channel. It uses OAuth2 credentials from a credentials.json file, and if necessary, guides the user through the authentication process. The retrieved analytics data is then saved to a CSV file named youtube_analytics.csv.

```py
import json
import os
import pickle
import csv
from datetime import date
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

# creds
with open("credentials.json", "r") as f:
    config = json.load(f)

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly']

def get_credentials():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("credentials.json", SCOPES)
            flow.redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:5000/'
            auth_url, _ = flow.authorization_url(prompt='consent')
            print(f"Please go to this URL: {auth_url}")
            auth_response = input('Enter the full callback URL: ')
            flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=auth_response)
            creds = flow.credentials
            with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)
    return creds

def fetch_youtube_analytics(channel_id):
    creds = get_credentials()
    youtube_analytics = build('youtubeAnalytics', 'v2', credentials=creds)
    
    today = date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
    response = youtube_analytics.reports().query(
        ids=f"channel=={channel_id}",
        startDate=today,
        endDate=today,
        metrics="views,likes,dislikes,averageViewDuration",
        dimensions="day",
        sort="day"
    ).execute()

    return response

def save_to_csv(data, filename="youtube_analytics.csv"):
    headers = ["Date", "Views", "Likes", "Dislikes", "Average View Duration"]
    rows = data.get('rows', [])
    
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        writer.writerows(rows)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    channel_id = "XYZ12345"
    analytics_data = fetch_youtube_analytics(channel_id)
    save_to_csv(analytics_data)
    print(f"Data saved to youtube_analytics.csv")
```

Trying to fetch Analytics using YouTube Analytics API from my  YouTube channel.